How to remove a specific queued up job from quartz?
I have a IJob class with the attribute '[DisallowConcurrentExecution]'.
We basically upload a file and do some processing.
Users trigger the job multiple times. For example, they initiate 10 uploads. So, while the first request is executing, nine others are queued up.
Sometimes, users send a request with wrong upload file. In such cases, they would like to remove this specific request from the queue.
Is this possible in quartz?
